# Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'omp_lib.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, mingw, fatal-error

I'm very inexperienced in this sort of thing, I'm trying to run some software called Zacros_2.0 for my senior physics project. As instructed, I have installed MinGW compiler in order to use makefile. When I run mingw32-make, it "can't open module file 'omp_lib.mod'", I don't understand what that is or what that means or how to fix it, I'm just following the instructions as laid out by the software's manual. Here is the full output after using the command: 'mingw32-make'

```
"Compiling: " lattice_handle_module
gfortran -c  -O2 -fopenmp -ffree-line-length-1024 ..\\lattice_handle_module.f90 -o lattice_handle_module.o
..\\lattice_handle_module.f90:98:13:

       !$ use omp_lib, only: omp_in_parallel, omp_get_thread_num
             1

Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'omp_lib.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
makefile:28: recipe for target 'lattice_handle_module.o' failed
mingw32-make: \*\*\* \[lattice_handle_module.o\] Error 1
```

I don't have the necessary knowledge to know what to do now. Can anyone give some dumbed down instructions for how to proceed?

I tried to download a different compiler, pacman, to help. But I couldn't get it working. I have no other ideas for what to do.